# Freemarker -> Sorting based on children - array first index value

Tags: freemarker

I want to sort my array based on children value(first index value of array)

```
<#assign members = [
            {"reference": ["a","b","c"]},
            {"reference": ["m","b","d"]},
            {"reference": ["f","b","dads"]}
        ]/>


<#list members?sort_by(["reference[0]") as member>
                <#list member.reference as x>
                  ${x}
                </#list>
            </#list>

 <#list members?sort_by(["reference","x?first") as member>
    <#list member.reference as x>
                  ${x}
                </#list>
            </#list>
```

Expected results from it:-

After sorting I should be able to achieve below format --->

members = [{"reference": ["a","b","c"]},{"reference": ["f","b","dads"]},{"reference": ["m","b","d"]}]

Answer (score 0):

At least in 2.3.29 you can't do that with `?sort_by`, as that can only traverse map-like containers, not list-like containers. Though, since 2.3.29 you can do this workaround:

```
<#list members?map(it -> { "k": it.reference[0], "v": it })?sort_by("k")?map(it -> it.v) as member>
```

In the future there probably will be a built-in to sort by a lambda result, now that 2.3.29 has lambdas. But until that, you either sort on the Java side, or do the above.